# Update User info using Graph API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

This is a question about updating a signed-in User's profile info using Graph API

I am using the tutorial at (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/javascript).
It lets you:

- sign in
- get signed in user info
- get calendar events
- create calendar events

It works perfectly and looks great.

However, I'm having a hard time updating the user info.
I stripped the sample code down to just getting the user info because I'm not dealing with calendar events.

Getting an access token, creating a client, and getting user profile works fine:

```
// Create an authentication provider
const authProvider = {
   
    getAccessToken: async () => {
      console.log('authProvider');
      return await getToken();
    }
  };
  
  // Initialize the Graph client
  const graphClient = MicrosoftGraph.Client.initWithMiddleware({authProvider});

  async function getUser() {

    return await graphClient
      .api('/me')
      // Only get the fields used by the app
      .select('id,displayName,userPrincipalName')
      .get();
  }
```

I replaced the content of the function getEvents() **to update the user**.

```
let user = {
        officeLocation: "Home Sweet Home"
    }

    try {
      return await graphClient.api('/me').update(user);
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      updatePage(Views.error, {
        message: 'Error logging in',
        debug: error
      });
    }
```

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update)

I wanted to update something basic like a User's officeLocation, however it did not work.

I correctly gave the proper permissions and scope in my App's permissions like so:
[image: permissions]

I keep getting Status Code 405 error, which means the HTTP method is not allowed. But documentation specifically told me to use the update function, which is PATCH.

[image]

Can someone provide working code (and permissions/scope attributes) to update a User's property so I know what the proper process is.

Thank you!

Update 9/22:

I also added the Global Administrator Role. Unfortunately, I'm still getting 405 Method ErrorMethodNotAllowed error.

[image: added admin role]

Update 9/23:

Used the Graph Explorer at (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer). When I attempted to use 'patch' on '/me', there is no permissions for me to consent to. And therefore, queries fail with "ErrorMethodNotAllowed".

The body is: { "jobTitle": "test" }

[image: used graph explorer]

Comment: Please add the global Admin role to the user which you are logged in with and try to update the location.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity 
I only have one user currently, so it defaults to the global admin role. It is the one and only user that I started my free trial with. 

I also tried: Default Directory > manage >properties > Access management for Azure resources > radio button (yes)
However, the radio button keeps defaulting back to (no). Does it have anything to do with me being on Free Trial account?

Nevertheless, none of it is working, and I'm still getting "Error 405, The method or operation is not allowed"

Comment: Please go to the Azure Active Directory and select --> Users --> Your user --> Assigned Roles and then add assignments, give global administrator role to that user and try.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity Hi Shiva, I followed your directions and assigned the 'Global Administrator' role to my user as shown in the screen shot added to the bottom of the original post. Unfortunately, I am still getting the 405 ErrorMethodNotAllowed error.

Comment: Please try it in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and see if it helps.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity Of course I have used the graph explorer, but to no avail. The weird thing is that once I selected the HTTP method to be "patch", the modify permissions should have "User.ReadWrite" or "User.ReadWrite.All". However, it is empty. There is no permissions for me to consent to. And obviously, when I hit query, it gives me "ErrorMethodNotAllowed".

Comment: Hi, Looks like you are directly using the MSA account. Please get the UserPrincipalName(UPN) of the Azure Active Directory user and then login to the Graph Explorer with those credientials and give Directory.AccessAsUser.All permission by selecting the gear button--> select Permission --> Directory.AccessAsUser.All and then try to update by giving officeLocation in JSON payload.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Moving this to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the user a Global Admin role and then try to call. Looks like you are directly using the MSA account. Please get the UserPrincipalName(UPN) of the Azure Active Directory user and then login to the Graph Explorer with those credientials and give Directory.AccessAsUser.All permission by selecting the gear button--> select Permission --> Directory.AccessAsUser.All and then try to update by giving officeLocation in JSON payload.
It worked for me.

Comment: Sorry about the lateness. Yes, it was permissions but on the application, not delegated. Once I set permissions for the application under B2C > your app > API permissions > MS Graph > Application Permissions, everything worked.

Comment: Four things here: 1. I wouldn't recommend giving the user Global Admin role to be able to update user info. 2. The user should be able to update it's own info with User.ReadWrite permission. 3. There's no longer an application permission called Directory.AccessAsUser.All 4. I even tried giving the application Directory.ReadWrite.All, but it still didn't work.