# Editing custom Azure B2C attributes using Microsoft Graph Explorer

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to use the Microsoft Graph Explorer to update a custom attribute I created in B2C named `GroupID`.

First, I get the `id` of the user I want to edit using this query:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/{myResourceName}.onmicrosoft.com/users
```

This returns the following JSON:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users",
    "value": [
        {
            "displayName": "User Name",
            "surname": "Name",
            "givenName": "User",
            "id": "ff46335221e1a365",
            "userPrincipalName": "user@username.com",
            "businessPhones": [],
            "jobTitle": null,
            "mail": null,
            "mobilePhone": null,
            "officeLocation": null,
            "preferredLanguage": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I'd like to add a value for `GroupID` for this user. The attribute itself does not appear in the above JSON, presumably because it does not yet have a value assigned.

I tried using this query:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/{myResourceName}.onmicrosoft.com/users/ff46335221e1a365
```

With request body:

```
{"GroupID": 1234}
```

But I get a 405 error:

> The method or operation is not allowed.

Am I using the wrong query? I tried to follow the guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

**UPDATE**

Attached is a screenshot of the request. In this screenshot, I omitted the `{myResourceName}.onmicrosoft.com` from the URL. But I've tried both ways and still get the 405 error.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-accounts-graph-api#extension-properties):

> Extension attributes in the Graph API are named by using the
> convention extension_ApplicationClientID_attributename, where the
> ApplicationClientID is the Application (client) ID of the
> b2c-extensions-app application (found in App registrations > All
> Applications in the Azure portal). Note that the Application (client)
> ID as it's represented in the extension attribute name includes no
> hyphens. For example:

```
"extension_831374b3bd5041bfaa54263ec9e050fc_loyaltyNumber": "212342"
```

So the real custom attribute name is `extension_{ApplicationClientID}_GroupID`.

Go to Azure AD -> App registrations to find the application id of the `b2c-extensions-app` application.

The `{ApplicationClientID}` is the application id without hyphens.

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/ff46335221e1a365

{"extension_{ApplicationClientID}_GroupID": 1234}
```

Comment: @JoshG Remove `{myResourceName}.onmicrosoft.com` in the request. Have updated the answer.

Comment: @JoshG If you still get the error, please provide a screenshot of the full request.

Comment: @JoshG `ff46335221e1a365` is not the real object id right? And the account you are using is an admin?

Comment: @JoshG How did you add the user into your B2C tenant? Is it a social account or local account?

Comment: @JoshG And please click on "Modify permissions" and check what permissions you have consented.

Comment: @JoshG And check this answer to see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63988409/update-user-info-using-graph-api?answertab=votes#tab-top.

Comment: @JoshG Sure. If it doesn't help, you could provide more details which I asked above so that I can do further investigation.

Comment: I was able to get it working using the legacy Azure AD Graph API with Postman. Your suggestion worked using the legacy API in Postman. I suspect it is a permissions issue with the new Graph API that I will need to investigate more closely. But I'm able to use the legacy AD Graph API for now. Thank you!

Comment: @JoshG Glad to know that:) Hope everything goes well.